# Power BI Service - Usage Metrics Report - Outdated usage data

Tags: powerbi

We have Power BI Premium and many times when I want to see the usage metrics of a report, I see the following message at the bottom of the report:

[image]

The problem is that I can never find where the dataset actually lives for these reports. Has anyone seen this before and has figured out how to refresh the usage metrics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the relevant workspace and click the settings icon in the top right.
[image]

[image]

Select Manage Group Storage. When the page loads, edit the url to add the following string to the very end.

```
?showHiddenUsageMetricsModels=1
```

Comment: Hi David and thank you. When I click on the Settings icon in one of my workspaces I do not see "Manage Group Storage". I see links for About, Premium and Azure Connections.  Clicking on any of these links does not show a Manage Group Storage.

Comment: I'll add a screenshot for the one I mean. It is the small cog on the toolbar.

Comment: Thanks David - Now I see the Usage Metrics dataset. But there are no links on the page to allow me to adjust the refresh settings for the dataset. This is really what I'm after.

Comment: Delete the dataset and it will be recreated. This usually fixes things like this.

Comment: Thanks David for all your help

Answer (score 0):

This view no longer works. Microsoft hides these now and they are no longer visible, even with the show hidden string appended to the URL.